# RESTful API, query params on PUT

Tags: rest, api-design

I am struggling with developing an API that follows RESTful best practices for my use case.

My db model looks something like:

Company:
    Id
    Name

Location:
    Id 
    Name 
    DefaultSetting

LocationSettings: 
    Id
    LocationId
    CompanyId 
    Setting

In the business model, not every company has set location values, so in many cases it will default to the value from Location.  If the user decides to change the value, then we will store their custom settings instead of using the default.

I was thinking of an API along the lines of:

GET /location-settings?companyId=id

GET /location-settings?companyId=id&locationId=id

PUT /location-settings?companyId=id&locationId=id

The idea is that when a user decides to change any setting, we will invoke the PUT route - it will update the location settings if custom settings exist for this company, or create a new entry in LocationSettings if it does not exist.

However, this seems like it might be an anti-pattern as normally I do not see query parameters used in such a manner on PUT routes to specify which resource to update.  In this case, I cannot easily provide an ID for the location-settings resource because it may or may not exist.  I did not want to use 2 separate routes (one for PUT and one for POST) because in the application's use-case this would get confusing i.e. from an end-user's perspective the default settings logic is hidden, so they always have location settings for their company and are simply updating them.

Another option I was thinking of was (OPTION 2):

GET /location-settings?companyId=id

GET /location-settings/locations/{locationId}?companyId=id

PUT /location-settings/locations/{locationId}?companyId=id

However, this seems strange because locations is not a sub-resource of location-settings.

A 3rd option I was considering was (OPTION 3):

GET /locations/location-settings?companyId=id

GET /locations/{locationId}/location-settings?companyId=id

PUT /locations/{locationId}/location-settings?companyId=id

Personally I liked this option the best.  However, I am not sure that referencing 2 collections like the first get route does without an ID is a good REST practice.

Any recommendations on this?

Answer (score 1):

It *sounds* like every company only has 1 'location-settings'.

If that that's true, you don't really need to add the location settings id to the url.

I might be wrong, but it seems like the only 2 routes you need are:

```
GET /company/{id}/location/{locId} - Return custom location settings OR default
PUT /company/{id}/location/{locId} - Update custom location for location
```

Comment: Thanks for your input!  It's one location setting per location per company.  So one company can have multiple location settings, but only one setting per location.

Comment: @webdevNewbie: I updated this. Some of this should probably be a comment, but would the above work for you.. and if not why?

Comment: So location exists independent of company, I think what you meant by location is location-settings, (which is also the resource I need to return)  i.e.:  GET /company/{id}/location-settings/{locId} (but then the location-settings resource doesn't necessarily have it's own id)

Answer (score 0):

> I do not see query parameters used in such a manner on PUT routes to specify which resource to update.

That's true, you don't.  But there is nothing wrong with doing it that way

```
PUT /x/y/z
PUT /x?y=z
```

Both of those URI are *fine*; general purpose components will do the right thing, URI templates describe them easily, and so on.  There are tradeoffs between them, of course (convenience for html vs convenience of relative references); but you could easily have one of them re-direct to the other if you discovered later that you wanted to change things.